# GCM push notification is nor working in Gionee p2m device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

*GCM push notificatin is not working when compile with my Gionee p2m device*

*1. permission are provide like*

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

*2. Receiver and service are register in manifest 
like*

```
<receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.tes.fitcompanyuser" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

 <service android:name="com.driver.pickji.gcm.GCMNotificationIntentService" />
```

*3. Receiver code is*

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
```

*4. and the service code is:*

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

Bundle extras;

public static int notifyID;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

JSONArray notificationdataArr;
JSONObject notificationObData;

private Preference mPrefs;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
    mPrefs = new Preference(ApplicationDriverPickJi.BASE_CONTEXT);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    extras = intent.getExtras();
    notifyID = (int) Math.random();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            if (extras.containsKey("pickUpRequests")) {
                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n" + extras.getString("pickUpRequests"));
            }
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gun_alert);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityLogin.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, Parcelable.CONTENTS_FILE_DESCRIPTOR);
            Notification n;
    try {
        n = new Notification.Builder(ApplicationDriverPickJi.BASE_CONTEXT)
                .setContentTitle("PickJi")
                .setContentText("You have a Notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pickji)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.gun_alert))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ApplicationDriverPickJi.BASE_CONTEXT
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you can try the quick start GCM [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) or more advance one [here](https://github.com/google/gcm). It should help you out.

Comment: this is not working also

Comment: What exactly does not working mean? Please edit your question so that the code is formatted and readble. Does this device have Play Store?

Comment: mine code and your suggestion both are working in normal device like samsung, moto g, google nexus micro max, but the problem occurred with GIONEE p2m device.